# How to disable process.stderr in node.js?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to do the equivalent of `node index 2> /dev/null` but I'm looking to do from inside `index.js`

Comment: "I'm looking to do from inside `index.js`"—why?

Comment: In any case, how are you printing to `stderr`? Are you using any logging libraries?

Comment: @Chris I'm not sure, I'm using some 3rd party library that launches an executable that outputs hundreds of logs per minute and it's preventing me from debugging. I need to control or filter these logs somehow but not sure how to go about it.